# Can firecrackers be used to subside thunderstorms due to cumulonimbus clouds

Tags: meteorology, clouds

Cumulonimbus clouds are associated with thunderstorms. Firecrackers which go up high in the sky and then burst into glittering show, can such crackers be injected in a cumulonimbus cloud and then burst to create a cloud seeding effect thus subsiding all the momentum building up in those clouds which can cause thunderstorms?

Comment: Firecrackers don't go high up in the sky. But airplanes do, and they are used for ->"cloud seeding", which has never been proven to actually have an effect on rain or lightning of a developed ts but does have negative effects on the environment. Which physical effect if at all should crackers have? Have you done a search to find an answer?

Comment: I remember watching a show on History TV18, where a guy was in a farm and the farm owner was using some kind of a blasting device to reduce the effect of a snowfall so that his fruit crop would not be affected. Firecrackers can be made to go higher up. Yeah, I should have tried sending one in the sky before posting this question.

Comment: If you shoot anything up that was "made to go higher", mind local regulations concerning airspace. Depending on where you do it violations might not be taken lightly ...

Comment: @mmt10 I've always been skeptical of cloud seeding, but believe some studies have shown it to have limited production (based upon what I've heard from meteorologists working in the field)... including limiting extreme hail size. So you'd need to more concrete to support such claims (likewise on the environmental impacts).

Comment: @JeopardyTempest: cloud seeding to dissipate ts. Not cloud seeding in general, but that's also controversal. You find studies in both directions as to its effectiveness. Silver iodide has no proven bad effects, dry ice and petroleum do, also concentrations are low they are. Side effects like missing precipitation elsewhere if it works are largely ignored when certain countries seed clouds to have nice and shiny sports shows. Cloud seeding doesn't add more water to the atmosphere. The usefulness for that urpose has also not been proven, afaik.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest: pretty fesh: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-01038-5, but there seems to be money to be made with cloud seeding, so also https://www.science.org/content/article/does-cloud-seeding-really-work-experiment-above-idaho-suggests-humans-can-turbocharge. So cloud seeding in general controversal, to dissipate ts missing proof? Anyway, it's done with aircraft and rockets, but maybe if you send enough overcharged firecrackers ;-)

Comment: @mmt10: To add to the controversy about [cloud seeding](https://csiropedia.csiro.au/Cloud-seeding/).

Comment: Joerg Kachelmann, prominent and sometimes noisy German speaking meteorologist about clud seeding: Pseudoscience https://www.t-online.de/nachrichten/panorama/id_84012166/kolumne-hagelflieger-sind-nichts-als-bauernfaenger.html. I find this paper cool: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/insr.12486. It says we did this and then that happened. But is this really the reason for that? Unclear ... Anyway, legally available (if at all, they are banned here) firecrackers only fly a few tens of meters high, maybe one hundred.